# Graceful shutdown and signal handling

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm trying to write an `asyncio` script which may be gracefully shutdown by sending a SIGHUP signal.

```
import asyncio
from signal import SIGHUP

def handle_sighup():
    print("sighup received")
    raise Exception()

async def main():
    asyncio.get_running_loop().add_signal_handler(SIGHUP, handle_sighup)
    while True:
        print("running")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

try:
    asyncio.run(main())
finally:
    asyncio.run(graceful_shutdown())
```

Naively I assumed raising an unhandled exception in the handler would propagate to the main coroutine and cause the `finally` block to execute. However, after printing "sighup received" the main coroutine continues to run.

I guess the callback is being run in an executor?

How can I refactor this code so that a signal can be handled to cause the main coroutine to be stopped and execution to drop down to the `finally` block?
Is there a better approach?

Comment: Do you have to use asyncio? [`trio`](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) handles exceptions as you would expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [sys.exit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit) in `handle_sighup`

```py
import asyncio
import signal
import sys

def handle_sighup():
    print("sighup received")
    sys.exit(0)

async def graceful_shutdown():
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    print("shutdown")

async def main():
    asyncio.get_running_loop().add_signal_handler(signal.SIGHUP, handle_sighup)
    while True:
        print("running")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

try:
    asyncio.run(main())
except SystemExit:
    asyncio.run(graceful_shutdown())
# finally:  # you can put it in finally instead of except, up to you
#    asyncio.run(graceful_shutdown())
```